# Unix shell filter by date time range and text

Tags: shell, unix, logging, awk

I have a log file and need to filter it by a range (from-to date/time) and by text using unix shell commands.

1. I use this for date range

```
awk '/2020-10-09 11:29:57.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/,/2020-10-09 11:41:45.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/' log.txt
```

2. And this for the text

```
grep "Status: passed" log.txt
```

So as the result, I get all the logs which are in defined period of time and then again all the logs with the text "Status: passed".

But does anyone know how to combine these commands? I need to use condition  AND somehow but I do not know how, never was in touch with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, not tested since no samples are given, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/2020-10-09 11:29:57.[0-9]{3}/,/2020-10-09 11:41:45.[0-9]{3}/{
  if($0~/Status: passed/){  print  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply printing everything between time range of `2020-10-09 11:29:57.[0-9][0-9][0-9]` to `020-10-09 11:41:45.[0-9][0-9][0-9]` which is used by OP itself. Then going inside block and checking if that current line has keyword `Status: passed` then print that line.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you want to filter by time range some timestamped sorted logs, you have to do a comparison, rather than matching the exact timestamp.

The reason for that is you can miss to match the lines if you have not an entry with the exact timestamp you want. For example in case you want to match e.g. from `11:00:00` to `12:00:00`, there could be entries only for `10:59:59` and `11:01:01` so matching the exact timestamp would not work.

---

Here is an example on how this works.

```
> cat log.txt
2020-10-09 11:29:56 Status: passed
2020-10-09 11:29:58 Status: passed
2020-10-09 11:30:40 Status: failed
2020-10-09 11:41:41 Status: passed
2020-10-09 11:41:45 Status: passed
2020-10-09 11:42:56 Status: failed
2020-10-09 11:42:59 Status: passed
```

This assumes logs are sorted by time and is efficient as it does not parse the whole file:

```sh
awk 'substr($0,1,19) >= "2020-10-09 11:29:57" {p=1}
     substr($0,1,19) > "2020-10-09 11:41:45" {exit}
     p && /Status: passed/' log.txt
```

In case your logs are not sorted, you have to parse the whole file:

```sh
awk 'substr($0,1,19) >= "2020-10-09 11:29:57" &&
     substr($0,1,19) <= "2020-10-09 11:41:45" &&
     /Status: passed/' log.txt
```

Output:

```
2020-10-09 11:29:58 Status: passed
2020-10-09 11:41:41 Status: passed
2020-10-09 11:41:45 Status: passed
```